# Swift running http request multiple times doesn't work

Tags: swift, request

I'm building a simple app that sends data to a server (reqres.in for testing) and receives an answer. When running the code from below, everything works, but once I run it again, it just says "started request" but doesn't do anything. What could cause this problem? Do I need to "close" or "end" this request/URLSession?

```
let url = URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = encoded
        print("started request")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // handle the result here
            print("data: \(String(describing: data))")
            print("response: \(String(describing: response))")
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")

        }.resume()
```

The debug output is:

```
started request
2020-07-31 18:04:43.626657+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_path_for_platform: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.631174+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.638227+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_path_for_platform: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.647951+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.657591+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_path_for_platform: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.667157+0200 TestApp[886:76137] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:43.667 TestApp[886/0x17111b000] [lvl=3] -[FBMLx_GIPPseudonymousIDStore initializeStorage] Shared App Groups unavailable
2020-07-31 18:04:46.213818+0200 TestApp[886:76276] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_path_for_platform: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:46.217361+0200 TestApp[886:76276] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2020-07-31 18:04:46.217 TestApp[886/0x16ef0f000] [lvl=3] -[FBMLx_GIPPseudonymousIDStore initializeStorage] Shared App Groups unavailable
```

Comment: why dont you work with `data, response and error` ? Try printing it and show us what it says